# IntegrationFlow memory leak

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have two integration flows that get files from two different directories.

```java
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow processBridgeFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(messageWaitingDirectory(), c -> c
                        .id("processFileRetry")
                        .autoStartup(false)
                        .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)))
                .handle(inDirectory) //FileWritingMessageHandler
                .get();
    }

   @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow processMessage() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(messageInDirectory(), c -> c
                        .id("processFile")
                        .autoStartup(false)
                        .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000))
                        .advice((CustomAdvice) ctx.getBean("createLogAdvice", TYPE_NAME))
                        .errorChannel(errorMessageChannel())))
                .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                        .subscribe(f -> f.handle(SERVICE_NAME, "init"))
                        .subscribe(f -> f.handle(SERVICE_NAME, "processMessage"))
                        .subscribe(f -> f.handle(SERVICE_NAME, "end"))
                        .subscribe(f -> f.handle(destinationDirectory))) //FileWritingMessageHandler
                .get();
    }

  @Bean
    public MessageSource<File> messageWaitingDirectory() {
        FileReadingMessageSource sourceReader = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        sourceReader.setDirectory(new File(messagesProperties.getWaitingDirectory()));
        sourceReader.setFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(MESSAGE_FILE_PATTERN));

        return sourceReader;
    }
    
   @Bean
    public MessageSource<File> messageInDirectory() {
        FileReadingMessageSource sourceReader = new FileReadingMessageSource();
        sourceReader.setDirectory(new File(messagesProperties.getInDirectory()));
        sourceReader.setFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter(MESSAGE_FILE_PATTERN));
        sourceReader.setAutoCreateDirectory(false);

        return sourceReader;
    }
```

The visualVM reports shows that the memory consumption keep growing even if there is no file to consume.
Here are screnshots on a few minutes without any file to consume  : [visualVM report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKFu8.png)
[VisualVM report object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZEw7.png)

How can I fix that ?

Comment: Did you try to get a heap dump of process and check what objects are loaded?

Comment: yes. I can see byte[], (22%), java.lang.Object[] (11%), int[](10%), java.util.TreeMap$Entry(7%), java.lang.reflect.Method(4%)
I have updated the post with a screenshot

Comment: Your screenshot looks normal: some growing then GC. We probably need more information about heap dump.

Comment: The memory is increasing by more than 150 MB before GC. It should be stable at a certain point of time

Comment: Ok. Any heap dumps pointing to Spring Integration components? Those TreeMap$Entry are so generic that it does not lead us to a specific point in the framework…